TradingView JS - UNIX timestamp data error when passing from PHP
I'm working with TradingView.js
https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts
https://unpkg.com/lightweight-charts/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js
When I format data with yyyy-mm-dd format it works fine. When I try to use UNIX time, which is supported in their documentation, the data doesn't format. Can't figure out why
const chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
width: 600,
height: 300,
timeScale: {
    timeVisible: true,
    secondsVisible: true,
},
});

const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries();

var examplePrices = [{ time: '2019-04-11', value: 80.01 },
    { time: '2019-04-12', value: 96.63 },
    { time: '2019-04-13', value: 76.64 },
    { time: '2019-04-14', value: 81.89 },
    { time: '2019-04-15', value: 74.43 },
    { time: '2019-04-16', value: 80.01 },
    { time: '2019-04-17', value: 96.63 },
    { time: '2019-04-18', value: 76.64 },
    { time: '2019-04-19', value: 81.89 },
    { time: '2019-04-20', value: 74.43 }];


var fiveDayPrices = [{"time":1725463800,"value":408.76},{"time":1725462000,"value":409.60}];

//lineSeries.setData(examplePrices);
lineSeries.setData(fiveDayPrices);

Here is how I'm generating the fiveDayPrices data with PHP
<?php

        $fiveDayPricesAndTimes = array();
        foreach($fiveDayStockPrices as $index => $dailyPriceInterval){
            $priceTime = strtotime($dailyPriceInterval["datetime"]); // This is already in seconds
            $priceValue = $dailyPriceInterval["close"];
            $fiveDayPricesAndTimes[$index]["time"] = intval($priceTime); // Now in seconds
            $fiveDayPricesAndTimes[$index]["value"] = floatval($priceValue);
        }
        
        $fiveDayPricesAndTimes = json_encode($fiveDayPricesAndTimes, true);

?>


Guess it must be due to the values you are using; if I replace the second time in your fiveDayPrices with 1755462000, it does draw. The values you are using there appear to only be half an hour apart?
